# replace a specific part of a string with the value of a variable with R

Tags: r, string

Hi I have an URL string but I need to replace a specific portion of the string to a variable

this is the code I have

```
todays_date <- as.character(Sys.Date())


   URL <- "https://api.performancehorizon.com/reporting/export/export/click.csv?start_date=2021-11-23+00%3A00%3A00&end_date=2021-11-24+00%3A00%3A00&campaign_id=1011l3888&convert_currency=USD&ref_conversion_metric_id%5B%5D=2"
```

I would need to change the date where it says `end_date` at this moment is 2021-11-23 to whatever value the variable todays_date is, in this case is the sysdate (11/24/2021) so the final string should be

```
"https://api.performancehorizon.com/reporting/export/export/click.csv?start_date=2021-11-23+00%3A00%3A00&end_date=2021-11-24+00%3A00%3A00&campaign_id=1011l3888&convert_currency=USD&ref_conversion_metric_id%5B%5D=2"
```

I imagine there should be like a wild card where the variable would be in.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `glue` can be helpful in cases like this. Notice I added in `{todays_date}` to your URL string.

```r
todays_date <- as.character(Sys.Date())

URL <- "https://api.performancehorizon.com/reporting/export/export/click.csv?start_date=2021-11-23+00%3A00%3A00&end_date={todays_date}+00%3A00%3A00&campaign_id=1011l3888&convert_currency=USD&ref_conversion_metric_id%5B%5D=2"

library(glue)
glue(URL)
```

Or of course, you can simply break up the URL and `paste` it back together.

```r
URL_1 <- "https://api.performancehorizon.com/reporting/export/export/click.csv?start_date=2021-11-23+00%3A00%3A00&end_date="
URL_2 <- "+00%3A00%3A00&campaign_id=1011l3888&convert_currency=USD&ref_conversion_metric_id%5B%5D=2"

paste0(URL_1, todays_date, URL_2)
```

Comment: this works, and I like that you can tell "hey here it is where it goes" but is there a way to do this without having to breaking the URL, just in one pass

Comment: @JuanLozano what do you mean in one pass? Like not having to put the variable in like that in the `glue` statement? Or not having to split the URL in the `paste0`? These are probably the two most simple ways to go about it.

Comment: not having to split the URL

Comment: If you want to use `paste()` like that then you would need to split it. The `glue` solution let's you do it without breaking up the URL by just substituting in the value.

Comment: This changed the question in order to answer it effectively answering a different question.  The other answer did directly answer the question.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck thanks for the explanation. Fair enough. I answered what I thought OP was trying to accomplish rather than the literal question. I do think my `glue` solution quite literally does what they asked for though. Note in the question they reference using a wild card.

Answer (score 1):

We may use `str_replace`

```
library(stringr)
str_replace(URL, "(?<=end_date\\=)\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}", todays_date)
```